# jquery html/css: adding a 'close' button to my div that was added on .click

Tags: jquery, html, css

new to jquery here, right now I have a working hide/show function when one radio button is selected. However, after I select a radio button there is no way to deselect all options and hide the div. Ideally id like to add a small 'X' that users could click which would reset my radio buttons and the amount of cars, I think you guys probably know just what I mean. Thanks a lot for the help!

html

```
<div id="myRadioGroup">

    2 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" value="2"  />

    3 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" value="3" />

    <div id="Cars2" class="desc">
        2 Cars Selected
    </div>
    <div id="Cars3" class="desc">
        3 Cars
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.desc").hide();

    $("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#Cars" + test).show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VgAgu/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this answer what you wanted?

```
<a href="" onclick="$('input:checked').removeAttr('checked');
  $('.desc').hide();return false;">Reset</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a class='close'>Close</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a.close').live('click', function(){
  $("input[name$='cars']").attr('checked', '');
  $("div.desc").hide();
});
```